# element.replaceWith in AngularJS directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive

I have been through the search results for this question, but none of the solutions work.

I have a directive:

```
   app.directive('pdf', function($compile) {
   return {
             restrict: 'E',
             scope: {filelocation: '='},
             link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

             var html = "";
             html = '<object type="application/pdf" data="http://someurl/' + scope.filelocation + '"></object>';

             element.replaceWith($compile(html)(scope));

             var currentElement = element;

             scope.$watch('filelocation', function(newValue, oldValue)
             {
                 console.log("Changed!");
                 var html = "";
                 html = '<object type="application/pdf" data="http://someurl/' + scope.filelocation + '"></object>';

                 var replacementElement = $compile(html)(scope);
                 currentElement.replaceWith(replacementElement);
                 currentElement = replacementElement;
             }, true);
           }
        };
   });
```

The $watch triggers when the filelocation changes - but the pdf itself doesn't update.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to empty the element and use the `$compile` transclude function to append the replacement html.

```
angular.module("myApp").directive('pdf', function($compile) {
    function newHtml(scope) {
        return '<object type="application/pdf" '+  
               'data="http://someurl/'+ 
                scope.filelocation+
                '"></object>';
    }
    function replaceHtml(scope, element, html) {
        var replaceLinkFn = $compile(html);
        element.empty();
        replaceLinkFn(
             scope,
             function transclude(clone) {
                 element.append(clone);
             }, 
             {futureParentElement: element}
        );
    };
    function linkFn(scope, element, attrs) {       
        scope.$watch(
            'filelocation', 
            function(newValue) {
                console.log("Changed!");
                var jhtml = newHtml(scope);
                replaceHtml(scope, element, jhtml); 
            },
            true
        );
    };
    return {
             restrict: 'E',
             scope: {filelocation: '='},
             link: linkFn
           }
});
```

The [DEMO on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mtko1fpw/).